# java.lang.nullpointerexception from a library in android

Tags: android, jar, kml

i was trying to create a library and JAR to get some points and create a kml file. So, in fact i created the library and the JAR file. Then i created a project to test my library, but the project returns to me a error.

```
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at br.ufc.kmzexporter.exporter.ExportarKmlUtil.addPoints(ExportarKmlUtil.java:71)
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at br.ufc.kmzexporter.exporter.ExportarKmlUtil.criarDocumento(ExportarKmlUtil.java:62)
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at br.ufc.kmzexporter.exporter.ExportarKmlUtil.expotar(ExportarKmlUtil.java:45)
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at com.example.testadorkmzexporter.MainActivity$ExportarKmlTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:90)
05-09 23:32:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(12249):    at com.example.testadorkmzexporter.MainActivity$ExportarKmlTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
```

In the code, i created the necessary objects to generate the KML file and called a ProgressDialog to call the method that will create and export the file.

I have no idea whats the problem.
My project is using the library that i created, and the library that i created uses methods of another library. I associated the two libraries in my project and put both JARs in the libs folder. Can someone help me?

Comment: The cause of the issue is in ExportarKmlUtil.addPoints(), line 71. What is there in that?

Comment: Thats the code around of the line 71:
'code'(private void addPoints(ArrayList<PointKML> points){
  List<Feature> placemarks = new ArrayList<Feature>();
  
  List<PointKML> pontos = points;
  for (PointKML ponto : pontos) {
   Placemark placemark = new Placemark();
   placemark.setName(ponto.getNome());
   
   String descricao = "";
   descricao += "<p>Afloramento: " + ponto.getNome() + " </p>";
   descricao += "<p>Detalhes: " + ponto.getDetalhes() + " </p>";)

The line 71 is: 'placemark.setName(ponto.getNome());'

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how to edit like a code. :S

Comment: The parameter(points) which you are passing might be became null.

Comment: I just dont understand how. I have three classes that i use. DocumentKML, PointKML and PointPhoto. A document have a list of points, and a point have a list of photos. I have a main activiy where a set the values manually, and then a asynctask that calls the method to export the kmz.